# Django: populate user selectable database fields in result

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a big Django database table which has more than 50 columns. I take input from the user (in array) which columns he wants to see in the search results. I am unable to map the user selected columns to the database.

```
        ticker_details = ticker_quotes.objects.filter(mkt_cap__lte = float(20))[:100]
        if(len(ticker_details) > 0):
        # print("length: ",len(data))
        for item in ticker_details:
            try:
                history[(item.symbol_id)] = {"title" : item.symbol_id, "change" : item.change} # How to select the database column using variable
            except:
                pass
        self.context["detail"] =  history
```

in the above code, I want to select the columns based on the user input but I get error when I try to access the column name using string variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. We can use getattr(model, fieldtoget) python function.

the above code will look like:

```
ticker_details = ticker_quotes.objects.filter(mkt_cap__lte = float(20))[:100]
    if(len(ticker_details) > 0):
    # print("length: ",len(data))
    for item in ticker_details:
        try:
            history[(item.symbol_id)] = {"title" : item.symbol_id, "change" : getattr(item, "change")} # 
        except:
            pass
    self.context["detail"] =  history
```